# How many years an app is downloadable in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

I wonder how many years an app is downloadable/distributed in Google Play Store after developer upload his/her app.

Comment: I don't think there is a strict limitation besides the validity date the self-signed app developer certificate is limited to (Google recommends to set a validity period of at least 25 years for newly created certificates).

Comment: Other than what Robert mentioned, I've had apps removed from the Play Store due to included legacy Advertising SDK being deprecated / considered using unsafe code OR the developer account not updating the listing for Content Rating.

Comment: There are 2 possible interpretations of this question: 1) the developer just uploaded the app once and not maintaining it anymore, or 2) they still continue providing updates to the app. The distinction is quite important due to Google renewing and enforcing their [Google Play Policies](https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies), so old apps can just be removed from Play Store if they're not complying to the latest policies.